# TaskList View in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, todoist

I've been trying to make to do list app,

I'm trying to make for each user their own to do list, with only tasks that they didn't complate,

properly get*context*data  doesn't eccepts filter function,cause there is no tasks displayes on the template

```
 `
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = "tasks"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["tasks"] = context["tasks"].filter(user=self.request.user)
        context["count"] = context["tasks"].filter(complete=False).count()
        return context`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter with [**`.get_queryset()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'tasks'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.object_list.filter(complete=False).count()
        return context
```

you might also want to filter on `complete=False` in `get_queryset`.

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.

Comment: it stil didn't work is,İt because of my template?

Comment: `{% for task in tasks %}
<h3>{task.title}</h3>{% endfor %}`

Comment: `<h3>{{task.title}}</h3>`.